# Get Laravel session data (Memcached) outside of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, memcached

Is there a way to get session data stored by Laravel outside of Laravel when using Memcached as session driver? (Only one part of the project is written in Laravel)

For example I put something in the session with Laravel:

```
Session::put('name', $user->name);
```

How can I retrieve this from another script (not in Laravel)?

I know I need a key. I've searched in Laravel files how the keys for sessions in Memcached are being generated, however I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel saves a key in a Cookie, which is called "laravel-session" by default. Decrypt this key and add a prefix ("laravel:" by default). This is the key in which laravel stores serialized session data about a user in Memcached.